# How to categorize the data present in array in this case?

Tags: javascript

I have got the array as following:

```
[
    {
        "name": "847_KK_0_KK_0tab1_checkbox",
        "cost": 10,
        "additionname": "Topping mango1",
        "addtionid": 100
    },
    {
        "name": "847_KK_1_KK_0tab1_checkbox",
        "cost": 12,
        "additionname": " Topping mango2",
        "addtionid": 101
    },
    {
        "name": "847_KK_1_KK_0tab2_checkbox",
        "cost": 12,
        "additionname": " Topping mango2",
        "addtionid": 111
    },
    {
        "name": "847_KK_1_KK_0tab2_checkbox",
        "cost": 12,
        "additionname": " Topping mango2",
        "addtionid": 111
    }
]
```

In the above array the name `tab1_checkbox` refers to the *first* quantity. Similarly the name `tab2_checkbox` refers to the *second* quantity.

I need to categorize the data as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < toppcrustsdata.length; i++) {
            var name = toppcrustsdata[i].name;
            var additionname = toppcrustsdata[i].additionname;

             toppings_quantitywise.push({
                        'name': 'Quantity'+,
                        'value': values
                    });

        }
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ku720du/7/

The desired output i am looking for is

```
[
    {
        "name": "Qty1",
        "values" : ["Topping mango1", "Topping mango2"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Qty2",
        "values" : ["Topping mango2", "Topping mango2"]
    }

]
```

I want to create the following javascript array with Jquery

Comment: What's the use of plus(+) in `'Quantity'+`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you show the result you want after processing the data.

Comment: What is the expected JSON structure?

Comment: Dude, OP, your question started off great with that nice clean array of objects and then turned in to nonsensical nothing when you listed the 2nd block of code.  Instead of the entire 2nd block of code, just list another nice clean array of objects that you DESIRE.  We'll take care of telling you the code to convert 'Array 1' into desired 'Array 2'.

Comment: The desired output i am looking is [
    {
        "name": "Qty1",
        "values" : "Topping mango1" , "Topping mango2"
    },
    {
        "name": "Qty2",
      "values" : "Topping mango2" , "Topping mango2"  
    }
    
    ]

Comment: @ArinCool , i have pasted the desired JSON structure i am looking for , please see my edited question .

Comment: What you pasted is not JSON. It is a javascript object

Comment: While this question is flagged, take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nelijosemi/2/edit

Comment: I pasted your code in jsfiddle , but it is  not working in fiddle , i am getting an error Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined could you pleaselet me know how to resolve it .